# How to send two request in one function

Tags: c++

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;
stream.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));
stream.connect("sitename","http");
    SOME REQUeST
stream.flush();

///////////////// New request to the different  site 


stream.connect("another site","http");
somthink here

stream.flush();
```

I think i need to close connect , but i dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the member function `.close ()` of the stream object, after closing the stream you are free to connect it elsewhere.

```
stream.close ();
```

---

#### Documentation:

- **[www.boost.org - ip::tcp::iostream - Boost 1.47.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/iostream.html)**
- **[www.boost.org - basic_socket_iostream::close - Boost 1.47.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_iostream/close.html)**